# FullCalendar React setting a Loading status loading events

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

In my React application, I'm using **FullCalendar.io**. The documentation is a bit sparse (and not React specific) in regards to setting a **Loading** status: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/loading

If I have:

```
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
```

...

```
 {loading ? <Spinner /> : null}

  <FullCalendar
    plugins={[ dayGridPlugin ]}
    initialView="dayGridMonth"
    loading={e => setLoading(e)} // With this line, it continually reloads the data source
    eventSources={[{
        url: '/api/calendar',
        method: 'GET',
      }]}
    />
```

It works perfectly if I comment out the loading line above, but if I want to trigger an indicator when it's loading, it puts the data load into an infinite loop.

It's like whenever anything changes, the calendar re-fetches the data. It does the same thing if I do:

```
loading={loadingFunction}
```

And:

```
  function loadingFunction (boolean) {
    setLoading(boolean)
  }
```

Note that it **does not do this if I use initialEvents,** but that provides less flexibility. (Then the loading works as expected.) But using events or eventSources, it puts it into a loading loop.

Comment: What does the setLoading(e) function do?

Comment: Just change the React state of loading to the true or false value passed.

Comment: I'm not a react user, but it's very unclear how that could cause fullcalendar to keep refetching events (which i think is what you're saying?)

Comment: Agreed; I've spent quite a while trying to figure out what's going on, but there's something about it that's strange.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that wrapping this in a useCallback:

```
  const loadingFunction = useCallback((boolean) => {
    setLoading(boolean)
  },[setLoading])
```

And wrapping the FullCalendar in a useMemo:

```
const fullCalendar = useMemo( () => <FullCalendar ... />  , [loadingFunction] )
```

Solves this issue. Hopefully I don't find any downsides to that...